# Rename Files in Sequential Order Using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10

I have a large number of files with no particular naming pattern. I'll like to name them in double digit numerical order, for example:

```
test1.txt --> 01.txt
1test.txt --> 02.txt
te1st.txt --> 03.txt
t1est.txt --> 04.txt
tes1t.txt --> 05.txt
_test1.txt --> 06.txt
_1test.txt --> 07.txt
_te1st.txt --> 08.txt
_t1est.txt --> 09.txt
_tes1t.txt --> 10.txt
```

How can I do this using a PowerShell command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Get-ChildItem` to enumerate the files piping to `Rename-Item` with [delay-bind script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.2#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters):

```
$counter = @{ value = 0 }
Get-ChildItem path\to\files -Filter *.txt -File |
    Rename-Item -NewName { '{0:D2}{1}' -f $counter['value']++, $_.Extension }
```